# CSS p:selectOneMenu

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to know, how to change the `background-color` of a [`p:selectOneMenu`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf).

I have tried this

```
 <p:selectOneMenu value="Select One"  style="background-color:red"  >  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
```

.....

But the background is still white.

Comment: It is better if you post HTML code in your question which is rendering in browser by using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `panelStyle` attribute as given below:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="Select One"  panelStyle="background-color:red"  >  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
```

Comment: @Fadhel Ghorbel: Can you tell me what HTML output generated by the above code?

Comment: <select id="j_idt77_input" name="j_idt77_input"><option value="">Select One</option><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option></select>

Answer (score 0):

The visual appearance is determinated by a surrounding `<div>` and a `<label>`. The easiest way is to give 'red' background to "everything" inside your `p:selectOneMenu`:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="Select One"  styleClass="redSelect">
```

while in your `<h:head>`:

```
.redSelect > * {
    background: red;
}
```

In addition to change the background of the drop-down menu, overwrite the background property of the following CSS class combination:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-items.ui-selectonemenu-list {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one, but the problem, i can not override the primefaces CSS.  When i add the property background:red; directly into the Web Browser under .ui-selectonemenu.ui-selectonemenu-label {
            
                
                display:block;
                border:medium none;
                white-space:nowrap;
                overflow:hidden;
                font-weight:normal;
                width:100%;
                float:left;
                background-color:red;
            } it works,
        But When i put it into the page(.xhtml), it doesn t work.

Comment: this is not the normal behavior. have you placed the rule `.ui-selectonemenu-items.ui-selectonemenu-list` between your `<h:head></h:head>` tags?

Comment: @FadhelGhorbel do you have any custom css which could affect the background-color of the list? Have you tried to create an empty page with the above css rule and with a `p:selectOneMenu`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right answer:

```
.ui-selectonemenu input.ui-selectonemenu-label{ background: red; }
```